# Add AngularUI to Umbraco backoffice

Tags: angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to add the AngularUI to use in the Umbraco backoffice, but i cant seem to get it working.
Can anyone shine some light to how should i achieve this?

Comment: Be aware that Umbraco uses an old version of AngularJS (v 1.1.5), so plugging in third party packages might not work as expected

Comment: Yeah i think that's the problem, i just checked and the angular.ui.js is getting included on my page.. Cant seem to get the pagination tag working tho

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new package manifest file for this where you reference the AngularUI javascript file.

To do this, create a new folder under the `App_Plugins` folder called `CustomBackoffice`. There you put the Angular UI javascript file.

Then create a new file in this same folder called `package.manifest` and add following code:

```
{       
    javascript: [
        '~/App_Plugins/CustomBackoffice/angular-ui.js'
    ]
}
```

See docs: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/property-editors/package-manifest

Comment: Hello, i do have that.. My package.manifest looks like this:

javascript: [ 
  '~/App_Plugins/custom/assets/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.js',
  '~/App_Plugins/custom/default/approval.resource.js',
  '~/App_Plugins/custom/default/defaultController.js',
  '~/App_Plugins/custom/ExportData/exportdata.controller.js',
  '~/App_Plugins/custom/ImportData/importdata.controller.js'
 ]

What do i need to do more so i can use for example the tag "pagination" on my view?